# Android APP update check from play store developed by kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, github, google-play

This is a soft phone android app developed by kotlin.
When I am opening the APP it is checking the update version with google play store and forced me to update. How can I turn off this app update check with play store[image]

```
{https://pastebin.com/GQSZD8Bi}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run App wifi turned off.

Search other versions of this App in google.

Comment: Internet is mandatory for this app.